# publishing and subscribing through rabbitmq server

Tags: python-2.7, rabbitmq, pika, python-pika

I need a scenario where one node send a message and another node starts waiting to get the message.

Each node after getting message sent turns into listener and after receiving message it turns into publisher again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look on this [RPC example](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-six-python.html). You will have to slightly modify it to exit listening and start publishing.

Comment: using channel.start_consuming() and channel.stop_consuming() at the subscriber method resolved the issue.